# How to completely remove a line from a file?

Tags: file, text, rust

How do I completely remove a line in Rust? Not just replace it with an empty line.

In Rust, when you delete a line from a file with the following code as an example:

```rs
let mut file: File = File::open("file.txt").unwrap();
let mut buf = String::from("");
file.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap(); //Read the file to a buffer
let reader = BufReader::new(&file);

for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() { //Loop through all the lines in the file
    if line.as_ref().unwrap().contains("some text") { //If the line contains "some text", execute the block
        buf = buf.replace(line.as_ref().unwrap(), ""); //Replace "some text" with nothing
    }
}
file.write_all(buf.as_bytes()).unwrap(); //Write the buffer back to the file
```

`file.txt`:

```
random text
random text
random text
some text
random text
random text
```

When you run the code, `file.txt` turns into this:

```
random text
random text
random text

random text
random text
```

Rather than just

```
random text
random text
random text
random text
random text
```

Is there any way to completely remove the line rather than just leaving it blank? Like some sort of special character?

Answer (score 1):

This part is bad-news: `buf = buf.replace(line.as_ref().unwrap(), "");`
This is doing a search through your entire buffer to find the line contents (without '\n') and replace it with `""`. To make it behave as you expect you need to add back in the newline. You can just about do this by `buf.replace(line.as_ref().unwrap() + "\n", "")` The problem is that `lines()` treats more than "\n" as a newline, it also splits on "\r\n". If you know you're always using "\n" or "\r\n" as newlines you can work around this - if not you'll need something tricker than `lines()`.

However, there is a trickier issue. For larger files, this may end up scanning through the string and resizing it many times, giving an `O(N^2)` style behaviour rather than the expected `O(N)`. Also, the entire file needs to be read into memory, which can be bad for very large files.

The simplest solution to the O(N^2) and memory issues is to do your processing line-by-line, and
then move your new file into place. It would look something like this.

```
//Scope to ensure that the files are closed
{
    let mut file: File = File::open("file.txt").unwrap();
    let mut out_file: File = File::open("file.txt.temp").unwrap();

    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);
    let writer = BufWriter::new(&out_file);

    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
       let line = line.as_ref().unwrap();
       if !line.contains("some text") {
           writeln!(writer, "{}", line);
       }
   }
}
fs::rename("file.txt.temp", "file.txt").unwrap();
```

This still does not handle cross-platform newlines correctly, for that you'd need a smarter lines iterator.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm could try removing the new line char in the previous line